# How to fix a NestedScrollView when click on editText with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-nestedscrollview

I have a NestedScrollView that contains a lot of components like a recyclerview, viewPager ...
I have an editText, for search.Also, an AppBar that contains a search icon.When I click on search icon the editText slideDown, and when I click a second time on in it slideUP.
My problem is when I scrolling the activity down for example, and when I click on search editText, the activity is not fixed, move up and out of the screen.
Here's main_activity.xml code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/whiteFour"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/searchButtonMain"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:tint="@color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Chart"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />
           <.....>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytSearchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/whiteFour"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/searchFields"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/icn_search_x"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:fontFamily="@font/cairo"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="@string/search_product"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:lineHeight="18dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/greyish"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">
<................>
```

When I click on search button :

```
 searchButtonMain.setOnClickListener {
            if (firstClickSearch) {
                val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    this, R.anim.slide_up
                )
                 //appending animation to textView
                lytSearchView.startAnimation(animation)
                lytSearchView.visibility = View.GONE
                firstClickSearch = false
            } else {
                 val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    this, R.anim.slide_down
                )

                //appending animation to textView
                lytSearchView.startAnimation(animation)
                lytSearchView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                firstClickSearch = true
            }

      
        }
```

So, what should I do to fix the NestedScrollView when click on search editText with Kotlin

Comment: Thing that you're looking for is called `android:windowSoftInputMode` in Manifest file for your activity tag. Try to use `adjustNothing` or `adjustPan`. I'm not sure from question what's your expected behaviour is but that'll do the trick.

Comment: No, I still have the same error. When I click on search icon in appBar, an edit text slide down, when the edit text slide down all the NestedScrollView move down, and when I click for second time on search icon the edit text slide up  and all the NestedScrollView move up, I want to fix the NestedScrollView